# MTG: Enchantments that require opponent to pay mana to attack

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I had a deck many years ago that was blue/white and used a blue enchantment that made players pay 2 colorless to attack.  I can't remember the name of the card, but it was around Mirage, no later than Urza block.  I also had [Kjeldoran Outpost](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kjeldoran%20Outpost) and [Thawing Glaciers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thawing%20Glaciers).

The main concept of the deck was to get out the mana generating diamonds from mirage, then blow away the lands with [Armageddon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Armageddon) and keep the opponent locked out of attacking for a while.

This card is stuck in my head and I can't seem to find the name of it anywhere.  I remember seeing it reprinted as a white enchantment sometime ago as well.

If anyone knows what this card might be, please let me know the name.  I have not found anything via searching so far.

Comment: This question is too localized. This isn't a vote-to-close, though, because I think there's probably an easy fix.

Comment: Alex, what do you mean?  This was driving me crazy and I couldn't figure it out on my own and figured the community would know, which they did.

Comment: "Too localized" is defined as "This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." I think the current formulation is specific enough that it's unlikely to help other users, particularly because they're not likely to search for the thing that gets them here, but a light edit -- maybe just a name change? -- is all that it would take to remedy that.

Comment: Hey @AlexP, I received a "Notable Question" badge for this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're thinking of [Propaganda](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPropaganda%5d) from Tempest, which came out right after Mirage.

[Ghostly Prison](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGhostly%20Prison%5d) is the white version and [Collective Restraint](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollective%20Restraint%5d) is a close cousin designed for multicolor-happy decks. (There's also the rather terrible [Koskun Falls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKoskun%20Falls%5d).)

Comment: There is also Dream Tides from Visions which has a similar effect: http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3638

Comment: Sphere of Safety is also worth mentioning. I've used that one to make attacks cost a few dozen mana per creature in standard (It was legal in original theros)

Answer (score 7):

You're right, a version was printed in white. Here's the cards you were thinking of:

- [Ghostly Prison](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGhostly%20Prison%5d)
- [Propaganda](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPropaganda%5d)

  #### More options:
- [Windborn Muse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWindborn%20Muse%5d) - If you want a body not an enchantment.
- [Norn's Annex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNorn%27s%5d%2b%5bAnnex%5d) - Could be a weaker or stronger version, depending on your opponent.
- [Collective Restraint](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollective%20Restraint%5d)- Domain Version. If you play 3+ basic land types, even better.
- [War Tax](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWar%20Tax%5d) - In late game if you have lots of mana, can really lock your opponents down.
- [Peacekeeper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPeacekeeper%5d) - Drawback: Also locks down your creatures, has upkeep cost.
  Upside: Hard lockdown.

Comment: Peacekeeper only has a normal (not cumulative) upkeep.

Answer (score 4):

More recently, there is the enchantment [Sphere of Safety](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSphere%20of%20Safety%5d) from [Return to Ravnica](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Return_to_Ravnica).

Answer (score 2):

Most of these pillow fort effects have similar wording, which includes the phrase "can't attack you".  Here's a [Scryfall search](https://scryfall.com/search?q=oracle%3A%2Fcan%27t+attack+you%2F+%28st%3Acore+OR+st%3Aexpansion%29&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name) for cards printed in a core/expansion set (no Commander or promo sets) which returns 19 results as of this answer's posting.

Results seem to be divides into a few categories:

- Permanents that tax or otherwise prevent opponents from attacking you. Examples include  [Blazing Archon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlazing%20Archon%5d), [Baird, Steward of Argive](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBaird%2c%20Steward%20of%20Argive%5d), [Propaganda](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPropaganda%5d), [Koskun Falls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKoskun%20Falls%5d)
- Permanents that prevent *some* creatures from attacking you. Examples include [Sandwurm Convergence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSandwurm%20Convergence%5d), [Reverence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReverence%5d)
- Single-turn effects such as [Chronomatic Escape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChronomatic%20Escape%5d) or [Forbidding Spirit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForbidding%20Spirit%5d)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ones mentioned above, there's also [Elephant Grass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElephant%20Grass%5d), which unlike the others has a cumulative upkeep (making it harder to keep around), but which trades that for costing just G, making it a perfect card for the Enchantress decks in Legacy.